# HtmlHelper is connection secured

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a `MVC4` helper and would like to find out from `HtmlHelper` class is request came from secured(`https`) connection or not(`http`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, assuming helper is of type `HtmlHelper<T>` or `HtmlHelper`

```
helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection;
```

or maybe a shortcut

```
helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection;
```